# How to remove non-alphanumeric from a UnicodeString in C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder, unicode-string

On a project I am working on, using Embarcadero C++Builder, all source files use `UnicodeString` when using strings.

I found this snippet to remove characters from `std::wstring`:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

//...

std::wstring FileHandler::removePunctuation(std::wstring word) 
{
    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), 
                  [](char ch){ return !::iswalnum(ch); }), word.end());
    return word;
}
```

But how do I apply the same algorithm to `UnicodeString`? Or, is there a similar feature with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

`UnicodeString` has [`begin()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.begin) and [`end()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.end) iterators, so you can use `std::remove_if()` exactly the same way as with `std::wstring`.

However, `UnicodeString` does not have an iterator-based `erase()` method like `std::wstring` does, but it does have an index-based [`Delete()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.Delete) method. `std::removee_if()` simply moves the "removed" characters to the end of the string, so you can use the iterator that `remove_if()` returns to calculate a starting index to delete from, eg:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

//...

UnicodeString FileHandler::removePunctuation(UnicodeString word) 
{
    auto iter = std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), 
                  [](WideChar ch){ return !::iswalnum(ch); });
    // Note: UnicodeString indexes start at 1, not 0!!
    word.Delete(std::distance(word.begin(), iter) + 1, MaxInt);
    return word;
}
```